# In App Purchases failed by user on apple ID dialogue

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I have a scenario with some steps as follow:

1. Restore Purchase Method called
2. Restore Results are fetched
3. Dialogue for apple ID and password canceled by user
4. `results.restoreFailedPurchases.count > 0`
5. After that restoreFailed result is follow

> SKErrorCode(_nsError: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot
>   connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot
>   connect to iTunes Store})

How can I get the user info object form that for error message accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the `SKError` to determine what the underlying error is. In the example you posted, code=2 means the user cancelled.

```swift
if let error = error as? SKError {
    switch error.code {
    case .paymentCancelled:
        // Handle user cancelled
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

`SKErrorCode` documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerrorcode